# field concept - historical and contemporay perspectives?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, history-of-philosophy, physics

Can someone give me some reference (or insight) on the development of the field concept in physics.

In particularly, the period between 17th century Newton/Leibniz notion of force/action-at-distance discussions and the 19th century discussions in electromagnetics (Maxwell, Faraday). There seems to be a gap in the literature how the "field concept" was shaped historically.

Additionally, what are some contemporary perspectives in the discpline of "philosophy of science" on what a field is (say, ontolog vs. nominalism, mathematical vs. physical)

Comment: Mary Hesse, [Forces and Fields: The Concept of Action at a Distance in the History of Physics](https://books.google.it/books?id=1ZyJOzZLrxwC&printsec=frontcover) (1962).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'll be adding that to my reading list. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I had a look at the contents; and it looks like a most excellent book; more philosophically and historically grounded than others I have seen.